# I need to take 2 columns in an excel sheet and convert them to a data range with column 1 as the headers

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data as follows in Excel. They are in 2 columns as a list.  The left column has an employee name and the second column is time/pc.

```
Employee    Time/pc
TE  0.616438356
TE  0.581896552
FL  0.474040632
AD  0.473251029
AD  0.491803279
TE  0.616438356
TE  0.652173913
TE  0.575
CG  0.744680851
JU  0.784313725
JU  0.568181818
JU  0.709459459
JU  0.227272727
AD  0.461956522
AD  0.555555556
JU  0.014285714
JU  0.692307692
```

I need easily convert this to a range where column 1 is used as the headers,  I need this remove the duplicates.  Then it needs to list all the values found beside each name, under each name.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: So, you want `TE`, `FL`, `AD`, etc. across row 1, then under each one, have their relative `Time/pc` values?

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly new to VBA, but am trying to answer question to support the community. I welcome any/all corrections to this code, but I tested it. It works and it does what they asked. It is not however optimised in any way, shape, or form.

I called the initial Sheet "RawData" and the new sheet "NewData"

```
Option Explicit

Sub Pivot()
Dim i, m, q As Integer
i = 2
q = 3

Do While Sheets("RawData").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
If Sheets("NewData").Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(Sheets("RawData").Cells(i, 1), LookAT:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        If Sheets("NewData").Range("A1") <> "" Then
                If Sheets("NewData").Range("B1") <> "" Then
                        Worksheets("RawData").Cells(i, 1).Copy
                        Worksheets("NewData").Activate
                        Cells(1, q).Activate
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("RawData").Cells(i, 2).Copy
                        Worksheets("NewData").Activate
                        Cells(2, q).Activate
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        q = q + 1
                Else
                        Worksheets("RawData").Cells(i, 1).Copy
                        Worksheets("NewData").Activate
                        Range("B1").Activate
                        m = ActiveCell.Column
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("RawData").Cells(i, 2).Copy
                        Worksheets("NewData").Activate
                        Cells(2, m).Activate
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            Else
                          Worksheets("RawData").Cells(i, 1).Copy
                        Worksheets("NewData").Activate
                        Range("A1").Activate
                        m = ActiveCell.Column
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("RawData").Cells(i, 2).Copy
                        Worksheets("NewData").Activate
                        Cells(2, m).Activate
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If


Else
Worksheets("RawData").Cells(i, 2).Copy
Worksheets("NewData").Activate
Sheets("NewData").Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(Sheets("RawData").Cells(i, 1), LookAT:=xlWhole).Activate
m = ActiveCell.Column
Worksheets("NewData").Cells(1, m).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues     
End If
  i = i + 1
 Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Check below code, it will help you get desired result.
Code posted by Emily Alden will work as well. This is shorter way.

```
Sub test()
Dim raw_data, new_data As Worksheet
Dim new_col_num, data_row_num, i As Long
Dim employee, time As String
Dim rng As Range

data_row_num = 1
new_col_num = 1

Set raw_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("raw_data")
Set new_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("new_data")

Do Until raw_data.Cells(data_row_num, 1).Value = ""

    employee = raw_data.Cells(data_row_num, 1).Value
    time = raw_data.Cells(data_row_num, 2).Value
    new_data.Range("A1").Activate
    Set rng = new_data.Range("A1:XFD1").Find(what:=employee, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
    new_data.Cells(1, new_col_num).Value = employee
    new_data.Cells(2, new_col_num).Value = time

    new_col_num = new_col_num + 1
    data_row_num = data_row_num + 1

    Else

    i = new_data.Cells(1, rng.Column).End(xlDown).Row + 1
    new_data.Cells(i, rng.Column).Value = time
    data_row_num = data_row_num + 1
    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this account for duplicates? To me it looks like a straight pivot, but I could be incorrect. They wanted to have only unique employees across the top and the the times listed under each employee.

Comment: I've edited the code. Now it will take care of duplicates as well. Thanks for review.

Comment: Hate to disagree, but this will leave blank rows occasionally. For example if Employee AA has three times and then you have a time for Employee BB it would get put on row 4 instead of row 1 where it belongs.

Comment: No.... it will print time of employee BB in row 1. however it will stop if there is any blank row in between in column A. here is the workbook... https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwkzD11CZOYYUmM2b3lKdy1JNlk